# How can remove a part of image name in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, replace, delete-file

I have a folder data that contains a list of images named as follow :

```
  AHTD3A0001_Para1.tif
  AHTD3A0002_Para1.tif
  AHTD3A0003_Para1.tif
      .
      .
  AHTD3A1012_Para1
```

I want to delete the first part of image name ( AHTD3A) in order to replace image names such as :

```
  0001_Para1.tif
 0002_Para1.tif
 0003_Para1.tif
      .
      .
  AHTD3A1012_Para1
```

please any suggestion for matlab code and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`strrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) to replace part of a string.

```
oldnames = {'AHTD3A0001_Para1.tif' 'AHTD3A0002_Para1.tif'};

newnames = strrep(oldnames, 'AHTD3A', '');

%  '0001_Para1.tif'    '0002_Para1.tif'
```

If the filename prefix isn't always the same and you simply want four digits followed by `_Para1.tif`. You could instead use regular expressions with [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html).

```
newnames = regexprep(oldnames, '.*(?=\d{4}_Para1\.tif)', '');
```

Or you can match it using [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) instead

```
newnames = regexp(oldnames, '\d{4}_.*', 'match', 'once')
```

Comment: thanks for the response, it works but I have a list of images (1012 images) arranged in the folder dataset, I want to replace the name and save the new name in the same folder. Can you help me and thaks in advance.